# Kafka broker occassionally takes much longer than usual to load logs on startup

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We are observing that Kafka brokers occasionally take much more time to load logs on startup than usual. Much longer in this case means 40 minutes instead of at most 1 minute. This happens during a rolling restart following the [procedure described by Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/post-deployment.html#rolling-restart). This happens after the broker reported that controlled shutdown was succesful.

**Kafka Setup**

- Confluent Platform 5.5.0
- Kafka Version 2.5.0
- 3 Replicas (minimum 2 in sync)
- Controlled broker shutdown enabled
- 1TB of AWS EBS for Kafka log storage

**Other potentially useful information**

- We make extensive use of Kafka Streams
- We use exactly-once processing and transactional producers/consumers

**Observations**

- It is not always the same broker that takes a long time.
- It does not only occur when the broker is the active controller.
- A log partition that loads quickly (15ms) can take a long time (9549 ms) for the same broker a day later.
- We experienced this issue before on Kafka 2.4.0 but after upgrading to 2.5.0 it did not occur for a few weeks.

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this? Or what additional information would be useful to track down the issue?

Comment: Are the log partitions on a network mount? If so, then the underlying network filesystem could be the culprit

Comment: Yes EBS is network storage, but it is a recommended storage type for Kafka logs by both Confluent and AWS.